# JS targeting wrong object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0a0yo575/10/

I am trying to display one box, in the top-left, at a time depending on what is active. But at the moment the JS is removing the point not the box?

```
$('.red-point').click(function() {
    $('.infobox').removeClass('hidn').addClass('show');
    $(this).removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
});
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you misspell? `.removeClass('hidn')` should be `.removeClass('hide')`?

Comment: Have changed spelling but no change in behaviour:

https://jsfiddle.net/0a0yo575/11/

And Marcos I have done that!

Comment: If you don't want to remove the marker why are you using `$(this)....addClass('hide')`?

Comment: and `$('.infobox').removeClass('hidn').addClass('show');` will obviously show _all_ of your infoboxes

Comment: No I want to remove the infobox not the marker. I was just following the example from the line below:

 $('.abs').click(function() {
       $('.abs').removeClass('green-point').addClass('red-point');
            $(this).removeClass('red-point').addClass('green-point');

Which, makes one marker green when clicked and if another is clicked that one turns green and the original goes back to red.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code `$(this)` refers to the marker you have clicked. So when you say `$(this).removeClass('show').addClass('hide');` you are hiding the clicked marker.

If you give your `.infobox` elements a `class` that matches the `id` of the clicked marker...

`<div class="infobox hide termini">Bar<br>Termini</div>`

...you could toggle them like this...

```
$('.red-point').click(function() {
    $('.infobox').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    $('.' + $(this).attr('id')).addClass('show');
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/0a0yo575/14/)

---

Personally, I would give each marker a data attribute containing the desired `infowindow` text and use this to populate a single `infowindow`...

```
<div class="infobox hide"></div>

<div class="abs red-point" id="termini" data-description="Bar<br>Termini">
     <a onClick="turnGreen(event)">
        <span class="num">1</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

```
$('.red-point').click(function() {
    $('.infobox').removeClass('hide').addClass('show').html($(this).data('description'));
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/0a0yo575/15/)